# codecademy 6 practice makes perfect

Tags: python

Can anyone explain this please?

---

```
def cube(number):
    number = (number**3)
    return number

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        cube(number)
        return number
    else:
        return False

by_three(3)
```

---

Oops, try again. `by_three(3)` returned `3` instead of `27`

Why does this not return `27`?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that in your by_three function you are returning the parameter "number" passed into the by_three function and not returning the result of the cube function. 
Your  code:

```
def by_three(number):

  if number % 3 == 0: 
   cube(number) 
  ## problem is right here you should return cube(number) not number
   return number 
  else: 
   return False
```

Fixed code.

```
def by_three(number):

  if number % 3 == 0: 
   return cube(number) ## note the change here

  else: 
   return False
```

Comment: so does cube(number) not change the value of number in the 2nd function and therefor not change the value of the number returned from the 2nd function?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Passing a primitive type to a function (i.e a integer which is the type of number in this case) doesn't change the value.  When you call the function like this: cube(number), the function cube() makes a separate copy of number for it to use as it executes, this behavior is different though for other data types.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not referring the returned value to variable number.The code will be like this.

```
def cube(number):
    number = (number**3)
    return number

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        number=cube(number)
        return number
    else:
        return False

print by_three(3)
```

Hope your problem is solved

Comment: Yes thank you very much this did fix the problem although i am not sure quite sure why

Comment: so i assumed that the line "number = (number**3)"would change the value of number and therefor the value of the return return - was i wrong?

Comment: @DamianMoore you returned the value from function cube but did not store it in the variable number as a result the program was returning the value of number as 3, since while calling the function by_three you reffered 3 to variable number.

Comment: If you answer has been solved please mark the correct answer and close the question @DamianMoore

Answer (score 0):

For example, we have two functions:

```
def function1(num):
    return num * 3
```

and second function

```
def function2(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        print(num)
        function1(num)
    return num
```

If you call `function(1)`, as expected it will return `1`
If you call `function(2)`, it will return `2` not `6`. WHY?

Lets analyze this `function2(2)`

```
def function2(num):  # num = 2 
        if num%2 == 0: # yes, it meets the condition 
            print(num)
            function1(num) # it steps into function 1, this return num*3 == 6 however we do not know where it is saved (its address is unknown). 
        return num # this 'num' it is just the argument == 2
```

Comment: so the 2nd function returns the initial value of number at the start of the function and not the modified value (modified by the call to the 1st function)? is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That's why your function return `3` instead of `27`. `cube` is actually executed and it did return 27 but you cannot find it.